Using phone mask in TextBox with WPF
I have a Window that contains this TextBox:
<TextBox x:Name="phoneTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,10" TextChanged="PhoneTextBox_TextChanged" />

As you can see, I'm calling a method name PhoneTextBox_TextChanged, that have the following code:
private void PhoneTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    var text = textBox.Text.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");

    if (text.Length > 11)
        text = text.Substring(0, 11);

    if (text.Length >= 6)
        textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2, 5)}-{text.Substring(7)}";
    else if (text.Length >= 2)
        textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2)}";
    else if (text.Length >= 1)
        textBox.Text = $"({text}";

    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length; // Mover o cursor para o final
}

Initially the code can format correctly up to the fifth number... from the sixth onwards the application crashes with the following message:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a
location within the string. Arg_ParamName_Name'

The error message is pointing to the second conditional that performs the logic:
textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2, 5)}-{text.Substring(7)}";

How can I solve this problem? The result I'm expecting is: (99) 99999-9999.

To be more precise, string is an array and you are simply trying to get elements from out of its range.
The offending lines are:
if (text.Length >= 6)
    textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2, 5)}-{text.Substring(7)}";

Here you check if Length is at least 6, but then your get substring starting from 7th position, which is wrong and immediately causes exception.
Correction could look like this
if (text.Length >= 8)
    textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2, 5)}-{text.Substring(7)}";


SOLUTION FOUND:
private void PhoneTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    var text = textBox.Text.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");

    // Limit the text length to a maximum of 11 characters
    if (text.Length > 11)
        text = text.Substring(0, 11);

    // Format the text based on its length
    if (text.Length >= 6)
    {
        // Ensure that we have enough characters for the substrings
        string areaCode = text.Length >= 2 ? text.Substring(0, 2) : text;
        string firstPart = text.Length >= 7 ? text.Substring(2, 5) : text.Substring(2);
        string secondPart = text.Length >= 8 ? text.Substring(7) : "";

        textBox.Text = $"({areaCode}) {firstPart}-{secondPart}";
    }
    else if (text.Length >= 2)
    {
        textBox.Text = $"({text.Substring(0, 2)}) {text.Substring(2)}";
    }
    else if (text.Length >= 1)
    {
        textBox.Text = $"({text}";
    }

    // Move the cursor to the end
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
}

Explanation: The error you're encountering, System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, occurs because you are trying to access a substring that exceeds the length of the text string.
